# How to disable Symmetrize in Sculpt Mode?

Tags: mirror, sculpting

I enabled Dyntopo, but Symmetrize seems to have been active already. As soon as I start stroking the mesh, it does it double.
I just don't see how to disable it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ensure the *Mirror* axes are all deselected:

[image]

---

In 2.8 these settings are in the *Brush* dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find the dropdown as mentioned earlier, but the later Blender still has settings under Symmetry > Mirror [x][y][z].

[image]