# How can I turn off mirroring in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

So, I am extremely new to blender, I am going to say outright. I have tried to fix this, but i can't seem to find any option that would fix the problem. When I sculpt on an object, it directly mirrors it, even though i have not enabled the mirror function, let alone touch it. I have double checked to make sure mirror wasn't on and it wasn't. and so on and so forth. I pretty much haven't changed any options or anything. if you could help me figure this out, that would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable/enable symmetry when sculpting, go to sculpt mode, then select/deselect the axes in the tool panel under the Symmetry/Lock section.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c76gj.png]

See Also : 
[How to disable Symmetrize in Sculpt Mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33641/how-to-disable-symmetrize-in-sculpt-mode)