# Question about Sculpt Brushes

Tags: sculpting

i am new on Blender and i have been modeling a sofa with pilows. Just wanted to create some creases on pillows. But when i try that, it sculpts as pixeled and two lines although i want it one unlike in some tutorials. I put the following picture to show it. How can i fix it ?[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvat1.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72582/how-can-i-turn-off-mirroring-in-sculpt-mode

Comment: Two lines because of symmetrizing like already suggested, pixelated because of too low geometry resolution. Either increase amount of subdivisions or if they're already high zoom in a bit to model and decrease size of the brush.