# Would like to know how to use the mirror modifier to help sculpt limbs

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, mirror

Good evening,
I'm a novice to blender,and i'm trying to play around in it a little bit by making a few character sculpts. However, I have no idea how to sculpts the limbs in a way that is has consistent symmetry, and mirrors one side actively as I'm sculpting. Is there a way for me to do this without manually copying and changing out each of the sides as I sculpt and modify them? (Just as a note for clarification, I am not looking to disable symmetry, I just want to know how to mirror to construction of limbs and other anatomy in real time while sculpting/modeling them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Symmetrize in Sculpt Mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33641/how-to-disable-symmetrize-in-sculpt-mode)

Comment: No, I am not looking to disable symmetry, I just want to know how to mirror to construction of limbs and other anatomy in real time while sculpting/modeling them

Comment: Don't you need the opposite, activate symmetry? You sculpt one limb and it will be automatically mirrored to the other side.

Comment: that's how I thought it should work, but it isn't that simple. That would be fine if the limbs were extruded originally from a central mesh, but my limbs are constructed from separate objects. Even when I did try to join the limbs and torso into one object, the limbs did not actively mirror one another

Comment: Well yes because that option only applies to what you're sculpting while the symmetry option is enabled. You probably want a mirror modifier then.